# My Pycharm IDE cannot connect debugger

Tags: python, anaconda, pycharm

My Pycharm IDE cannot connect debugger in one of my anaconda environment. As I try to debug some code it says:
*Connection to Python debugger failed Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking*
the exit code is -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I moved the project to another anaconda environment and the debugger opens normally.

What could be wrong in the former environment?

Answer (score 7):

Disable "PyQt compatible" checkbox in the **Settings** under **Build, Execution, Deployment** --> **Python Debugger**.

Then debug again the code and it should works.